# ISO 27001 - resetting passwords for SQL Server accounts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, authentication, password

We are implementing security changes in order to pass an ISO 27001 audit.
We are in the process of setting all domain accounts (user accounts, admin accounts, service accounts) to have their passwords changed automatically by our information security management system (Thycotic).

The question is, do we need to also change the non-domain SQL Server authentication accounts (such as the "SA" accounts) and if so do you know of a way to do this?

Is is standard to reset the passwords for these SQL Server authentication accounts?

Answer (score 1):

The [ISO/IEC 27001:2013](https://www.iso.org/standard/54534.html) paper **Information technology -- Security techniques -- Information security management systems -- Requirements** is a standard that:

> ...specifies the requirements for establishing, implementing, maintaining and continually improving an information security management system within the context of the organization. It also includes requirements for the assessment and treatment of information security risks tailored to the needs of the organization. The requirements set out in ISO/IEC 27001:2013 are generic and are intended to be applicable to all organizations, regardless of type, size or nature.

If this standard defines that you ***should*** change the passwords every so often to ensure security, then by all means go ahead and do this.

### Regarding SQL Server

Changing the password of an account is as simple as logging in to the instance and setting off the command:

```
ALTER LOGIN [sa] SET PASSWORD = 'ThisIsMyN3wSecurePassw0rd' 
GO
```

### Answering Your Question

> Is is standard to reset the passwords for these SQL Server authentication accounts?

There are no standards, regarding resetting the `[sa]` login's (or for that matter any other SQL Server authenticated account's) password.

But if you **want to** abide by the standards laid out in ISO/IEC 27001:2013 then you probably **should** change the SQL Server authenticated account's passwords at **regular intervals**.

> regular: existing or happening repeatedly in a fixed pattern, with equal or similar amounts of space or time between one and the next; even:

<sup>***Reference:*** [regular](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/regular) (Cambridge Dictionary)</sup>

That means that *once a year* can be considered *regular*.

Answer (score 1):

> Is is standard to reset the passwords for these SQL Server authentication accounts?

It *should* be, though what people actual do may differ. ISO 27001 concerns information security which should include all routes to access the information. Any policies covering security should cover local and domain level accounts.

As a matter of best practise, where possible you should probably do away with local accounts completely so you can control authentication via the domain accounts. Even if that is not practical in your circumstances, it is strongly recommended that you disable `sa` and use more fine-grained access control.